What is difference between Vercel's custom domain and Vercel's alias
What do "custom domain" and "alias" mean in Vercel? Are they the same thing?
I am assigning an alias to the release branch using the Vercel API, specifically example.com. Additionally, I have configured the Vercel domain settings for the preview environment and the release branch.
In this scenario, I am unable to assign an alias from the GitHub Actions workflow. The alias is being assigned using the Vercel API as documented here: Vercel API - Assign an Alias.
Could the issue be that the domain is already configured in Vercel, causing a conflict when attempting to assign the alias via the workflow?
I have attempted to assign the alias using the Vercel API. My expectation is for the release aliases to be assigned through the workflow.

No, they are not the same thing. I will give you a response to your question right away, however: prefer domains added to your projects. You can also use the Vercel API for that. Only, and only if, the "production" and "preview" environments do not fit your specific need you should use aliases. But I challenge even that approach, as you can also use the Vercel CLI + multiple projects (one project for production, many others for arbitrary preview environments).
If you want to use aliases, ensure they were not added to any projects as a 'domain that belongs to a project'.
A little bit of history here: when the Vercel platform was now, the only thing available to developers to configure domains related to deployments were aliases. Basically, you would do a deployment (no environment differentiation at the time) and then assign an alias manually with an API request, or the CLI now alias. It was also possible to configure an array in the alias key of now.json, but I digress.
As you can see, the alias API has endured a lot of transformation around it. Now you can add domains directly to projects, and even attach a specific branch to certain domains. Soon you should be able to create custom environments, that extend preview and production as you wish. Therefore, the alias API is certainly losing the appeal, and I expect it to be phased out in a few years.
